# How to detect a keylogger in a USB keyboard

Tags: windows, usb, malware, keylogger

I recently got an USB keyboard. I want to investigate if the microcontroller of the keyboard may host a keylogger and how could it interact with a Windows OS. My understanding is that, once Windows recognizes the USB device, it will get the appropriated driver from a secure Microsoft DB, so even if it is recording the key strokes, it cannot run by itself any SW to send them anywhere. I'm leaving aside the possibility of having a SW keylogger.

Is it possible that a USB keyboard could host a keylogger and that Windows could give it control to run a process to send the information to an address?

Comment: This is how the FBI got a crime boss.   They couldn't crack his PGP encryption so they swapped his keyboard out for one with memory in it.  Then they came back and swapped the keyboard back.  Voila, they were able to decrypt all his prior and future communications.

Comment: Look to the right and you will see a lot of related questions on this subject.  Perhaps one has the answer you are looking for.

Comment: I'd first consider how important a target you consider yourself to be, & the chances that you either chose at random from a shelf in a store, or were intentionally sent by a randomly-chosen online equipment supplier, just exactly the correct keyboard that contained the logger - also how whoever sourced it is planning to get it back from you to decipher later.... Foil hats are free.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are many other ways to capture keystrokes, from email-transmitted malware to worms on the local network to phreaking the electrical signals from a perfectly normal keyboard.  In terms of least-obtrusive ways to capture keystrokes, there are also little USB passthrough devices which plug into the PC's USB and provide a USB port on the other side.  The passthrough is invisible to the PC except for slight power draw, and the malcontent can attach and retrieve the device at his convenience.

Comment: Windows supports a group polioy that only allows connecting USB devices if they match specific device ids.  That's how you would stop a fake keyboard that's a key logger.  Of course if you whitelist the fake keyboard this solution isn't helpful

Comment: *it cannot run by itself any SW to send them anywhere.* this is false.  I could design hardware that claimed to be a keyboard to a USB host but would not only capture your keystrokes but was also a Apache server and would automatically connect to any open access points.  I could also in theory make that same device brute force secured access points silently until successfully.  I won't be linking to anything that explains how.

Answer (score 0):

In most likelyhood the keylogger would store the keystrokes in memory on the key logger for later retrieval.

It would theoretically be possible for the keyboard to contain a USB hub, and in addition to the keyboard enumerate another device like a USB key with auto-run, which could possibly then issue keystrokes to tell the OS to send data or do something else (and, I guess, could be timed to wait a long time with no keys being pressed before inserting) to reduce the chance of being caught.  I posit that this could be done automatically using the keyboard to provide the inputs required to actually run the key logger.